# Calling Super when Dynamically Create Types using Multiclass Inheritance in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, multiple-inheritance

How does one dynamically create a `type` that inherits from multiple base classes via cooperative inheritance? I have tried a couple options, each of which have had their own issues. My current code works like so:

```
    cls_map = {"SomeClass" : SomeClass, "OtherClass" : OtherClass}


    def get_type(classes: list[str]):

        def constructor(self, *args, **kwargs):
            pass

        types: list[type] = [cls_map[c] for c in classes]
   
        return type("MutableEntity", tuple(types), {
            "__init__": constructor
        })
        
    # Get type, instantiate object
    dynamic_cls: type = get_type(['SomeClass', 'OtherClass'])
    dynamic_instance = dynamic_cls(...)
```

When I execute

```
assert isinstance(dynamic_instance, SomeClass)
```

It returns `True` (which is great!).

The problem I'm running in to is that I don't know how to make `constructor` correctly call `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`.

I tried:

```
 def constructor(self, *args, **kwargs):
            pass
```

But got the following error:

`E       TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`

My theory is that this is because the argument `self` is `None` for some reason. Any suggestions how to resolve this? My subclasses are designing to function using cooperative inheritance, so being able to call `super()` is important.

Full Code:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(*args, **kwargs)
        self.some_class = True


class OtherClass:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(*args, **kwargs)
        self.other_class = True


cls_map = {"SomeClass": SomeClass, "OtherClass": OtherClass}


def get_type(classes: list[str]):
    def constructor(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    types: list[type] = [cls_map[c] for c in classes]

    return type("MutableEntity", tuple(types), {
        "__init__": constructor
    })


# Get type, instantiate object
dynamic_cls: type = get_type(['SomeClass', 'OtherClass'])
dynamic_instance = dynamic_cls()

assert hasattr(dynamic_instance, 'some_class')
assert hasattr(dynamic_instance, 'other_class')
```

Comment: The zero-argument form requires a class statement to work

Comment: In any case, what code did you try *exactly**?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I Added a 'full code' section.

Comment: That is just the same code. Look, in the future you need to create a [mcve]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I added my exact MRE.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
def constructor(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(klass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

klass = type(
    "MutableEntity", 
     tuple(types), 
     {"__init__": constructor}
)

return klass
```

The zero-argument form only works (through compiler magic) inside of a class definition statement.

Note, your base classes need to call `super` as well, or else this isn't going to work (without writing adaptor classes)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't hardcode my base class's this way. There's no guarantee which ones will be used.

I'm currently working on a method that uses `type(self).__mro__[1]` to reference the highest-level base-class. I then call that class's `super` which propogates to `init` functions in the classes that are further down the MRO.

Comment: @CCD that doesn't make any sense - if you are trying to use cooperative multiple inheritance *then the classes should cooperate*. If you aren't going to do that, then write an *adaptor* that does.